# Exclude specific fields in all nested document in mongoose query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a **ride** Collection with **trips** as a field, **trips** is a map where the keys are different **years**. I want to query the collection but exclude the passengers field in each trip

```
const ride = new Schema(
    {
        boat_operator: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        trips: {
            type: Map,
            of: {
                passengers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
                available_seats: { type: Number, required: true }
            },
            default: new Map()
        }  
    }
    )
```

I tried this

```
const rides = await Ride.find({ status: 'waiting' }).select("-trips.*.passengers")
```

I tried to select all the items in **value** then remove the corresponding passengers field in each

It had no effect

this is what the response looks like

```
[
    {
        "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bf5",
        "boat_operator": "6328c434a98212a7f57c4edc",
        "trips": {
            "2019": {
                "passengers": [],
                "available_seats": 5,
                "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bfe"
            },
            "2020": {
                "passengers": [],
                "available_seats": 5,
                "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bfc"
            },
            "2021": {
                "passengers": [],
                "available_seats": 5,
                "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bfa"
            },
            "2022": {
                "passengers": [],
                "available_seats": 5,
                "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bf8"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I want to exclude the passengers field in the returned document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would solve it

```
const rides = await Ride.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "status": "waiting" } },
  { $project: { "trips": { $objectToArray: '$trips' } } },
  { $project: { 'trips.v.passengers': 0 } },
  { $project: { "trips": { $arrayToObject: '$trips' } } }
]);
```

[nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) [mongoose](/questions/tagged/mongoose)

Here's the returned document

```
{
  "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bf5",
  "trips": {
    "2019": {
      "available_seats": 5,
      "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bfe"
    },
    "2020": {
      "available_seats": 5,
      "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bfc"
    },
    "2021": {
      "available_seats": 5,
      "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bfa"
    },
    "2022": {
      "available_seats": 5,
      "_id": "632a1669279c86f4ab3a4bf8"
    }
  }
}
```